# Problema con eventFilter y Key_Return en un QDialog con botones

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Tengo el siguiente código dónde intento hacer uso de `eventFilter`:

```
class Ticket(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):

        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("ticket.ui",self)
        self.D_Aceptar.clicked.connect(self.productos) #QPushButton

    def total(self,total1):
        global n
        n = total1
        tr = round(n, 2)
        self.l_total.setText(str(tr)) #lineEdit que recive el valor
        self.pago.setFocus() # QLineEdit
        self.pago.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self,obj,event):
        if obj is self.pago and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
                self.calculo()
        return QDialog.eventFilter(self,obj,event)

    def calculo(self):
        pago = float(self.pago.text())
        operacion = pago-n
        opf =round(operacion, 2)
        op = str(opf)
        self.cambio.setText('$ {}'.format(op))


    def prductos_specifico_bar(self,bar_code,sucursal):
        new_total = 0
        ref  = db.reference('/Productos_Bar/'+str(bar_code))
        r0 = ref.get()
        total = 0
        try:
            for key in r0.items():
                if sucursal == 1:
                    if key[0] == 'exe1':
                        val = key[1]
                        total = val
                        if total == 0:
                            self.cambio.setText('Producto sin inventario')
                            break
                        else:
                            new_val = total-1

                            ref.update({
                                'exe1':new_val
                            })
                elif sucursal == 2:
                    if key[0] == 'exe2':
                        val = key[1]
                        total = val
                        if total == 0:
                            self.cambio.setText('Producto sin inventario')
                            break
                        else:
                            new_val = total-1

                            ref.update({
                                'exe2':new_val
                            })
                elif sucursal == 3:
                    if key[0] == 'exe3':
                        val = key[1]
                        total = val
                        if total == 0:
                            self.cambio.setText('Producto sin inventario')
                            break
                        else:
                            new_val = total-1

                            ref.update({
                                'exe3':new_val
                            })
        except:
            pass

    def producto_especifico_id(self,identi,sucursal):
        try:
            if int(identi) > 4:
                self.prductos_specifico_bar(identi, sucursal)
            else:
                ref  = db.reference('/Productos_Bar')
                r1 = ref.get()
                for key in r1.items():
                    res1 = key[1]['id']
                    if res1 == identi:
                        new_ref = key[0]
                        self.prductos_specifico_bar(new_ref,sucursal)
                        break
                    else:

                        self.l_codigo.setText('ID no existe')
                        break
        except:
            self.l_codigo.setText("No se coloco un valor valido")

    def productos(self):
        for i in lista1:
            self.producto_especifico_id(i, sucursal_id)
```

Teóricamente, cuando el evento dentro de `self.pago` sea igual a `key_return` debe ejecutar el método `self.calculo()`.

El problema es que sin embargo ejecuta también el slot asociado al botón `self.D_Aceptar` que es `self.productos`

¿Qué me falta o en qué me equivoqué?

Comment: ¿Por qué instalas el eventoFilter en el botón también?

Comment: @FJSevilla, no disculpa ese es un evento que ya no puese en seguida lo quito de la publicación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu botón está configurado como el [botón por defecto](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#default-button) el cuál es activado cuando se presiona la tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd> dentro del diálogo, que típicamente indica que el usuario a completado la configuración, acepta y cierra el diálogo.

El botón configurado como `default` en un `QDialog` tiene dos propiedades diferenciales:

- Es activado cuando se pulsa la tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd> en el diálogo, por lo que se llama al slot correspondiente si tiene uno asociado a la señal `connect` como se ha comentado.
- Será mostrado con un frame extra, por lo que (dependiendo del estilo de la GUI) aparecerá resaltado, aunque no tenga el foco.

Hay dos propiedades de `QPushButton` que entran en juego:

- [**`default`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#default): indica si un botón es o no el botón por defecto, por lo  que podemos configurar un botón como botón por defecto o no usando el argumento `default` durante la instanciación o posteriormente mediante el método `QPushButton.setDefault(bool)`. Dado que solo puede haber un botón por defecto simultáneamente en un `QDialog`, si definimos varios con esta propiedad solo se tomará en consideración el primero (mientras la propiedad no cambie).
- [**`autodefault`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop): si en un `QDialog` ningún botón tiene `default=True`, el primero que acepte este rol  gracias a la propiedad `QPushButton.autoDefault`, es automáticamente configurado como `default` cuando el diálogo es mostrado.

  Por defecto es `False`, excepto cuando se instancia un `QPushButton` siendo su padre un `QDialog`, entonces  la propiedad [`autodefault`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop) es `True` por defecto.

  Igualmente puedes especificarlo al instanciar vía argumento `autodefault` o posteriormente mediante el método `QPushbutton.setAutoDefault(bool)`.

Por el nombre del botón sospecho que es esta precisamente su función por lo que si quieres preservarla, lo que puedes hacer es simplemente evitar la propagación del evento cuando el <kbd>ENTER</kbd> se produzca dentro del `QLineEdit` retornando `True`:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if obj is self.pago and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
            self.calculo()
            return True
    return QDialog.eventFilter(self, obj, event)
```

Ten en cuenta que esto solo evitará que el botón sea activado si el <kbd>ENTER</kbd> se produce en `self.pago` (lo digo por si tienes más widgets en el `QDialog` que deban responder también al mismo evento).

Si quieres evitar tener un botón como `default` puedes simplemente especificarlo en todos los botones del QDialog:

```
btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(default=True, autoDefault=False)
```

o bien en *QDesigner* en las propiedades del botón:

[image]

En este caso podrías simplemente usar la señal `QLineEdit.returnPressed() simplemente`.

Comment: tengo solo otro boton el boton de cancelar, ese boton tambien quedara fuera de la ejecucion del evento key_return como el otro boton

Comment: en total son 2 botones el self.D_Aceptar y Sself.D_Cancelar, al agregar la linea return True el segundo boton tambien quedara fuera del evento key_return()

Comment: @Revsky01 al bloquear el evento en el QLineEdit este no se propaga a los posibles widgets padre. Por otro lado, solo puede haber un botón como "default" simultáneamente en un QDialog, he editado la respuesta con información extra a ver si se entiende mejor.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda